# How to remove trailing zero?

Tags: java, excel

i use `jxl.write.WritableCellFormat.WritableCellFormat` when I download Excel.

Excel download is fine.

But cellFormatStyle does not come out the way I want.

-now problem
1 -> 1.000
0.003 -> 0.003

-i want
1 -> 1
0.003 -> 0.003

What should I do?? plz help me.

Below is the code of the problem.

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = new NumberFormat("0.###")

WritableCellFormat cellStyle = new WritableCellFormat(numberFormat);
```

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what exactly your question is ... is this showing all of your code?

Comment: `0.###` should work... I can't reproduce with plain old `DecimalFormat`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if the right 4 characters are less than zero and change the number format if they are not.  So assuming your data is in cell A1:

```
If Right(Range("A1"), 4) < 1 Then
Else
'This means it is not < 1 and therefore not a decimal
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "0"
End If
```